# iOS Swift dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier causing overlap

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This has been driving me mad, I have look at about every post on around in regard to this.

I am using custom tableview cell classes and XIB files. It all works fine, until I scroll the table view off screen (that old chestnut). I know it has to do with the **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** method and not clearing the old data. However I have no idea how to implement this.

Once the cell scrolls off screen., it causes an overlap and continues to add images to the cell.

```
let cell: DetailHeaderTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailHeaderTableViewCell") as DetailHeaderTableViewCell
```

From what I have found, I need to implement something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

UIImageView *defaultImageView;
UILabel *customLabel;

if (cell == nil) {
    // create the cell and empty views ready to take the content.
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
} else { ... }
```

However I cannot work out how to achieve this in swift.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [UITableViewCell's `prepareForReuse`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) method.

If you're using custom UITableView cells, you need to implment this method to clear out any old data from your cells before they are reused.

Comment: I now have a problem where when I revisit the view, all of the cell constraints are now wrong. i.e. they all return to the default 44pt unless if I scroll the cells off the screen. any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a separate & new question than the original one you asked.  Why not ask a new question, showing the code of what you did in "`prepareForReuse`"?